# Strange Message Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have an active project on visual studio community 2017, before ten days or so, a strange message is showing without knowing what is the origin package or component that is causing this to appear.

The message is not allowing me to build the project any more
[image]

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, the message is not showing on other projects that I have

Comment: Search on the dependencies of your project. Maybe you must pay for one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a trial package that I've installed from NuGet, the strange thing is the dialog is not giving any indication from which package it is coming from.

NuGet should handle this or the Developer of the package should? anyway it took three days from me to know the reason